# Extract common code into own module

Tags: java, architecture, maven, javafx

I'm finding myself in a situation where I need to define common behaviour and implement it depending on the environment (minecraft server or javafx runtime). The simple graph below describes my idea.
[image]

Maybe a few more notes to get the big picture.

A user starts the gui module and makes some changes to the default settings. These changes are then written to a yml file which will be read by the plugin module when the server boots up. Explained in more detailed this would mean the following:

1. a NoCraftingChallengeGUI instance is created
2. the user modifies said instance through the gui
3. user exports settings
4. NoCraftingChallengeGUI instance is serialized into a yml file
5. minecraft server boots up
6. yml file deserialized into a PluginNoCraftingChallenge (should workbecause the constructor in both objects is exactly the same)

I have a hierarchy of model classes defined in the api module.

```java
public abstract class Challenge {

}
```

```java
public class NoCraftingChallenge extends Challenge {
    private Set<Material> allowedToCraft;
    private Set<Inventory> forbiddenToUse;
    serialize and deserialize methods

}
```

In the gui module I use the class as a controller/inside a FXML controller.
(ChallengeController is an abstract controller extending Challenge)

```java
public class NoCraftingChallengeController extends ChallengeController AND NoCraftingChallenge {

bunch of javafx UI methods to display a GUI
I need access to both sets from NoCraftingChallenge AND
from ChallengeController because its the parent controller

}
```

In the plugin module I use the class to register events and send chat messages.
(PluginChallenge is an abstract class extending Challenge)

```java
public class PluginNoCraftingChallenge extends PluginChallenge AND NoCraftingChallenge {

bunch of minecraft event handler and other methods.
I need access to both sets from NoCraftingChallenge AND
PluginChallenge because its the parent class

}
```

Comment: The generic names in your code make it difficult to answer your question. Can you rename them to the real names, or use representative real names?

Comment: Instead of inheritance, have you considered composition? And if you have considered composition, why didn't composition work for your problem?

Comment: I changed the example to my real world classes.
Haven't thought about using composition enough. After a quick thought using interfaces in the api with another class containing just the common implementation and then implementing the interface in each module respectively could work. Will try it tommorow and post an answer/additional question here.

Comment: That is good information, but what is the design problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem statement is inside the code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

With the hint from [Greg](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/442973/extract-common-code-into-own-module?noredirect=1#comment973569_442973) to use composition I came up with the following.
In api the following interfaces exist:

```java
public interface Challenge extends Commonable {

    @Override
    ChallengeCommon getCommon();

    public ItemStack getUIDisplay();
}
```

```java
public interface NoCraftingChallenge extends Challenge {

    @Override
    NoCraftingChallengeCommon getCommon();
}
```

and some classes which will be shared by both gui and plugin.

```java
public interface Common {
    <T> TypeAdapter<T> getTypeAdapter();
}
```

```java
public class NoCraftingChallengeCommon extends PunishableChallengeCommon {

    private final Set<Material> allowedToCraft;
    private final Set<InventoryType> forbiddenToUse;

    public NoCraftingChallengeCommon() {
        this(
                List.of(),
                Set.of(Material.ENDER_EYE),
                Set.of(InventoryType.WORKBENCH, InventoryType.CRAFTING)
        );
    }

    public NoCraftingChallengeCommon(List<Punishment> punishments, Set<Material> allowedToCraft, Set<InventoryType> forbiddenToUse) {
        super(punishments);
        this.allowedToCraft = allowedToCraft;
        this.forbiddenToUse = forbiddenToUse;
    }
//(de-)serialization methods
}
```

In plugin it looks like this:

```java
public abstract class PluginChallenge implements Challenge {

    private final ChallengeCommon common;

    protected final ChallengesReworked plugin;

    public PluginChallenge(ChallengeCommon common) {
        this.common = common;
        this.plugin = JavaPlugin.getPlugin(ChallengesReworked.class);
        register();
    }

    @Override
    public ChallengeCommon getCommon() {
        return common;
    }

    public abstract ItemStack getUIDisplay();
}
```

```java
public class PluginNoCraftingChallenge extends PluginChallenge implements NoCraftingChallenge, Listener {
    public PluginNoCraftingChallenge(NoCraftingChallengeCommon common) {
        super(common);
        ChallengesReworked.registerListener(plugin, this);
    }
    @Override
    public NoCraftingChallengeCommon getCommon() {
        return (NoCraftingChallengeCommon) super.getCommon(); //"ugly" casting
//minecraft server specific methods
    }
```

The same structure is implemented in the gui module.

So in a nutshell I keep the inheritance inside each module and implement everything from the api module. The instances then contain a (data) class which contains the same logic for both modules.